# ionic cordovaSQLite plugin doesn't work on physical device

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic-framework, application-icon

I want to add SQLite data to my mobile application in ionic I had followed the tutorial step by step in the following site https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/ but still it dosen't work on physical device,any advice.
in the index.html i put the following code
 `

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<script src="lib/ionic/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>



<!-- Needed for Cordova/PhoneGap (will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>`
```

in my app.js I wrote the following code first code

```
     var db=null;
     var myApp=angular.module('myApp',['ionic','ngCordova'])
    .run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
     $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("test.db");
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text)");
    console.log("hello");
})
```

})

so I have created a table named people and in my login controller I'll insert one row to people table

```
controller('loginController',function($scope,$cordovaSQLite){

    var query = "INSERT INTO people (id,firstname, lastname) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [1,"khaled", "omar"]).then(function(res) {
        $scope.name=res.insertId;
    }, function (err) {
        $scope.name="error";
    });
```

and in the login.html i wrote {{name}} but when i run it on browser i get the followin error Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined and I run it on the physical device but still doesn't work

Comment: I don't think you'll get any answer with this much information. You should probably show your code, what is expected, what are the errors etc.

Comment: ok i wrote the details, thank you for your advice

Comment: Glad you used my tutorial!  If you look carefully at `db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("test.db");` you'll notice that is not correct.  The parameter is not a string.  It needs to be an object. Try putting `{ name: "test.db" }` in there instead and let us know how it goes.

Comment: @Nic: on your tutorial you write "test.db" and not the object. What is the correct one?

Comment: I believe the API changed and you want to use a string, not an object.

Answer (score 1):

the code is working well, it seems the error comes from a problem in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

The code below works for me.

I don't know why, but you have to put your database creation code inside the `onReady` method before the `if` statement like this:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform,$cordovaSQLite) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {  

    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name:"my.db", location:1});              
          $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testTable(id integer primary key, col1 text,col2 tex)");

    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }                        
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use following code.

`db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "dbname.db", location: 1});`

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

$ionicPlatform.ready() must fire before you can use cordova.

Answer (score 0):

This actually worked, thanks [musakkhir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3894854/musakkhir-sayyed) and [anuj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5409427/anuj)

```
db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "dbname.db", location: 1});
```

`location:1` is important.